# Instruments to check for leaks in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, instruments, valgrind, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to Mac OS X Mountain Lion and found out that `valgrind` is still not compatible with Mountain Lion.

I have a 600 line C code that I need to check against memory leaks.

What are possible ways to do it other than valgrind? Can I use Xcode instruments?

Comment: Install Linux in a VM and run valgrind there.

Comment: Instruments will work fine for C, as long as you have it setup as an Xcode project.

Comment: Of course... Xcode is yelling at me claiming I have duplicate symbols. When on the command line everything builds perfectly. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/valgrind/     Valgrind is available on OSX, but 600 lines of code... I would go with careful tracking of each malloc call.

Comment: It is available on OS X for Lion. It is not compatible with Mountain Lion. The code is pretty complicated. I checked for leaks manually but I want to double check to be completely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the [clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). It's pretty awesome tool for finding bugs in the code.

It's better than valgrind in the fact that it does static analysis rather than running the code — so it can find bugs which you rarely reach. However, it is more likely to trigger false positives as well. And it's not as mature as valgrind.